# Getting a late start on being Maavir Sedra for the year

Tags: halacha, calendar, shnayim-mikra

I remember hearing when I was younger that ואלה שמות - is Roshei Teivos V'Chayav A'dam L'haavir H'sedra S'htayim M'ikra V'echod T'argum.

If someone who has not been [Maavir Sedra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shnayim_mikra_ve-echad_targum) so far this year is inspired to start being Maavir Sedra this week - should they start from B'reishis or should they start from this week's Parsha? (sources)

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43913/9643

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shulhan Aruch (O"H 285) says you have until Shemini Aseret Bedieved to complete Shenayim Mikra. Thus, start from the beginning of what you missed (see Yalkut Yosef for more details).