# Getting a head start on Shnayim Mikra

Tags: calendar, time, shnayim-mikra

[(Inspired by this question)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13169/5)

Can one get a *head* start on Shnayim Mikra? Would it count if someone either started early (perhaps during the weeks with no Sedra in Tishrei), or just had some spare time and went on to the next week's (and then the next and the next) Parashah?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98279/9643

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Mishneh Torah*, in [Hilkhot Tefilah u-Bhirkat Kohanim 13:25](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2213.htm#25), says:

> אף על פי שאדם שומע כל התורה כולה, בכל שנתו בציבור, חייב לקרות לעצמו **בכל שבוע ושבוע, סדר של אותה שבת**--שניים מקרא, ואחד תרגום

In English( taken from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920178/jewish/Chapter-Thirteen.htm)):

> Although a person hears the entire Torah [portion] each Sabbath [when it is read] communally, he is obligated to study on his own **each week the sidrah of that week**, reading it twice in the original and once in the Aramaic translation.

*Shulchan Arukh*, in [Orach Chayim 285:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40431&st=&pgnum=396), says the same, and adds, in 285:3, that from Sunday onwards is considered "with the congregation"( "עם הצבור" in [Berakhot 8a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=8&format=pdf); in English see [here](http://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_8.html)).

In short, the answer is: No, one can't fulfill the obligation of *Shenayim Miqra ve-Echad Targum* for that week when starting before the end of the previous week's public Torah reading.

Answer (score 11):

[According to Rabbi Israel Joseph haCohen Rappaport](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46283&st=&pgnum=17), the earliest time that you can start saying Shnayim Mikra B'Dieved is from Shabbos Mincha for the next week and L'Chatchila from Sunday.

Comment: His proof that min hamuvchar you should not start until Sunday is very weak.  Why does the ability to still read last weeks parsha preclude me from reading a parasha that the tzibur already started?  Does shnaim mikra limit me to 1 parsha?

Comment: @YDK: Lechatchilah (not b'diavad) from Shabbat Minchah, and Minchah is taken to mean Zman Minchah, meaning the earliest possible time to pray Tefillat Minchah.

Comment: Min hamuvchar is Friday before the Shabbos on which it's read. [M"B 286:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=126).

Comment: @AdamMosheh Do you have a source for your assertion? If so, you might want to consider adding it as an answer to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98279/9643).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it would work. The Gemara  [(TB Berakhoth 8a)](http://dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=brachos&daf=8a&go=Go) says to finish it with the tzibur, not ahead of the tzibur.

Comment: A reference+link to the gemara in question would make this answer much more valuable.

Comment: Brachos 8b says mashlim im hatzibbur

Comment: I take issue with your answer 1) In Shilchan aruch Siman 285 it says you can begin from the beginning of the week. 2) Does the Gemara mean that I have to say the last Passuk together with the Baal Korei? It is brought (I don't remember where) that the GRA used to break up the Sidra throughout the week.

Comment: The gemara doesn't  mean you literally read it at the same time, just by the week.

Comment: the Gra's hanhaga is cited in the Mishnah Berurah as evidence that one need not learn it exclusively on friday.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  There is a statement on [this webpage](http://www.ouradio.org/shnayim_mikra/article/faqs_about_shnayim_mikra) that seems to imply that certain poskim consider Shnayim Mikra to be an annual obligation, not a weekly one.  Consequently, a person would be permitted to "get a head start on" upcoming Torah portions as long as he doesn't start before Simchat Torah.

Comment: Following the given link takes me to http://www.ou.org/torah/index. A better link might be: [http://www.ou.org/index.php/torah/article/faqs_about_shnayim_mikra/#.UVnbHJZ_bK0](http://www.ou.org/index.php/torah/article/faqs_about_shnayim_mikra/#.UVnbHJZ_bK0)