# Preferred approach when behind in Shnayim Mikra

Tags: shnayim-mikra

If someone is behind in shnayim mikra, is it better for them to skip to the current parsha or to continue from where they have gotten up to?

What if they estimate that they will be more likely to cover everything if they do it one way and not the other?

Answer (score 3):

Do last week's פרשה first, according to [Halachapedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shnayim_Mikra_V%27Echad_Targum#cite_note-46):

> If one misses a week one should read the previous Parsha's Shenayim Mikra and then the current weeks Parsha. [46]
>
> ...
>
> [46] Sh”t Bear Moshe 5:79 writes that if one misses a week one should read the previous Parsha's Shenayim Mikra and then the current weeks Parsha. Rav Shlomo Zalman Halichot Shlomo (Tefillah 12:36), Ketzos haShulchan 72:9, Chazon Ovadyah (Shabbat, vol 1, pg 314), and Daily Halacha (by Rabbi Mansour) agree. However, Sh”t Yitzchak Yiranen 1:32 says one can make up a parsha out of order. Halichot Shlomo (Tefillah 12:37) adds that if one did begin the current week's parsha before one finished the previous one, one may finish it.

Comment: I assume this applies to when I am 6 or 7 weeks behind as well. ( I happen to be caught up at the writing of this comment)

Comment: @YEZ It seems like it would be fine בדיעבד either way, the best would be to do all 7 פרשיות before the coming שבת, in order.  (Sounds like fun ;))

Comment: What does the Mishnah Berurah or other more well-known Poskim hold ?!